# Different result from Golang db.query and actually running on DB

Tags: mysql, go

I have a MySQL DB on which I run a query which gets the top row from each group (according to some grouping criterion):

```
SELECT ranked.id, ranked.os, ranked.version, ranked.timestamp, agent_metadata.*
FROM
  (SELECT *,
     @os_rank := IF(@current_os = os, @os_rank + 1, 1) AS os_rank,
     @current_os := os
   FROM default_version
   ORDER BY os DESC, timestamp DESC
  ) as ranked INNER JOIN agent_metadata ON ranked.os = agent_metadata.os AND ranked.version = agent_metadata.version
WHERE os_rank = 1;
```

When I run this query on my DB (using DataGrip) I get the expected result.

However, when I run the same query from my Go code using `db.query`, instead of getting 2 rows, I get 5 rows.

I have some logic which builds the query but before running it I print it to the log:

```
// ... build query
query := qb.String()

logger.Debugf("Executing: %s", query)

if rows, err := repository.connection.Query(query); err != nil {
    return defaults, errors.Wrap(err, "get default versions")
} else {
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {

        result := DefaultVersionExtended{}

        err := rows.Scan(
            &result.Id,
            &result.DefaultVersion.OS,
            &result.DefaultVersion.Version,
            &result.Timestamp,
            &result.AgentMetadata.OS,
            &result.AgentMetadataExtended.Version,
            &result.AgentMetadataExtended.Name,
            &result.AgentMetadataExtended.Description,
            &result.AgentMetadataExtended.ReleaseNotesUrl,
            &result.AgentMetadataExtended.UploadTime)

        if err != nil {
            return defaults, errors.Wrap(err, "get default versions")
        }

        defaults = append(defaults, result)
    }

    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        return defaults, errors.Wrap(err, "get default versions")
    }

    return defaults, errors.Wrap(err, "get default versions")
}
```

This is the output from the log:

> time="2017-07-25T15:07:47+03:00" level=debug msg="Executing: SELECT
>   ranked.id, ranked.os, ranked.version, ranked.timestamp,
>   agent_metadata.* FROM (SELECT *, @os_rank := IF(@current_os = os,
>   @os_rank + 1, 1) AS os_rank, @current_os := os FROM default_version
>   ORDER BY os DESC, timestamp DESC) as ranked INNER JOIN agent_metadata
>   ON ranked.os = agent_metadata.os AND ranked.version =
>   agent_metadata.version WHERE os_rank = 1"
>   class="auroradb.agent_repository"

If I copy-paste the query from the log into my DB console and run it I get the correct result (2 rows):

[image]

However, my unit test fails, because I expect the result to have 2 rows but it actually has 5:

> Error:      "[{%!s(int=1) {windows 1.2.3} {{windows 1.2.3 My name This is
>   a test agent for windows http://notes-heaven.com} 2017-07-25
>   12:07:45.099 +0000 UTC} 2017-07-25 12:07:45.38 +0000 UTC} {%!s(int=3)
>   {windows 1.2.3.1} {{windows 1.2.3.1 My name 2 This is a second test
>   agent for windows http://notes-heaven.com/1} 2017-07-25 12:07:46.237
>   +0000 UTC} 2017-07-25 12:07:46.519 +0000 UTC} {%!s(int=4) {windows 1.2.3.2} {{windows 1.2.3.2 My name 3 This is a second test agent for windows http://notes-heaven.com/3} 2017-07-25 12:07:46.801 +0000 UTC}
>   2017-07-25 12:07:47.082 +0000 UTC} {%!s(int=2) {mac 1.2.3.2.M} {{mac
>   1.2.3.2.M My name 3.M This is a second test agent for windows http://notes-heaven.com/3} 2017-07-25 12:07:45.662 +0000 UTC}
>   2017-07-25 12:07:45.944 +0000 UTC} {%!s(int=5) {mac 1.2.3.5.M} {{mac
>   1.2.3.5.M My name 3.M This is a second test agent for windows http://notes-heaven.com/3} 2017-07-25 12:07:47.364 +0000 UTC}
>   2017-07-25 12:07:47.653 +0000 UTC}]" should have 2 item(s), but has 5

The returned result is in fact the entire data from agent_metadata. It's as if the entire logic selecting the top result or each group didn't work.

I'm using [go-sql-driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) as driver.

Comment: Is your `repository.connection.Query(query)` executing the query only once?

Comment: Or what about the behaviour of the `@...` varaibles? Is it the same in Go as in DataGrip?

Comment: Yes, just once. And my intuition also goes to blaming the @ but I pass the query as a string, so I'm not sure how it can go wrong. The string is printed correctly by the logger. Why would it not pass correctly to the DB?

Comment: On a side note, your whole else block is unnecessarily nested. Since you return in the if, you don't even need an else.

Comment: I need the else because it uses the rows from the if. I agree it's a little annoying.

Comment: What driver are you using to connect to mysql? [This one](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) or some other one?

Comment: @Dina Just get your `rows, err` and check the `err` on the next line. You do it in your else clause `err = rows.Err() ... ` (which could actually be `if err = rows.Err(); err != nil ...`)

Comment: Can you share the code where the `defaults` variable declared and used? Does it already has something int it?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, that's the one. Good point. I will edit the question.

Comment: @Dina did you check **mysqld**'s _general query log_ to see what sql statements are sent to the mysql server by both the Go app and DataGrip? Seems like one is interpreting the query differently from the other before sending it to the server.

Comment: @mkopriva You're right. I've been planning to do this but didn't get a chance. Problem is this is actually an AuroraDB instance on Amazon and I don't have easy access to manage it. But I just installed a local MySQL so I have more control over it and I can turn on the logs.